# Rails Count How many article

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am trying to show into article#index how many comments where on each articles.

So i have the following models

```
resources Article do
 resources Comments do
 end
end
```

I know in each article I can do the follow and this would work:

```
@count = @article.comments.find(:all).count
```

And just show in the view count. But then problem comes when i am in an index file and not sure how to show how many comments exist for this event atm.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I would strongly suggest to use a counter cache for this, as this might generate some heavy load on the SQL side of things. Watch this episode on RailsCasts to see how it's done: http://railscasts.com/episodes/23-counter-cache-column

Comment: Kitto's comment should be posted as an answer and should be accepted as the right answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

articles_controller.rb

```
def index
  @articles = Article.all
end
```

articles/index.html.erb

```
<% @articles.each do |article| %>
  comments in article <%= article.comments.count %>
<% end %>
```

The nested routes (comments within articles) matters more in terms of your create/destroy routes for comments. Also be sure to add `accepts_nested_attributes_for :comments` in your Article model. This will allow you to do stuff like this:

for example, in articles_controller.rb

```
def show
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])

  # creates a new comment object with atricle_id already initialized
  @comment = @article.comments.build
end
```

**Edit**

If you do start caring about performance, I agree with Kitto's comment.

Add this migration:

```
class AddCommentsCountToArtices < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :articles, :comments_count, :integer, null: false, default: 0
  end
end
```

And change your relation declaration in your Comment model to this:

```
belongs_to :article, counter_cache: true
```

Then you can make calls like this `article.comments_count` to get the count instead of `atricle.comments.count`. And it's great if the count is 0, because it doesn't even make the query (p. 195 of The Rails 3 Way).

If you're curious about how counter_cache works: it adds a callback to the belonging class (in this case, the Comment class) that updates the comments_counter attribute on the parent article each time a comment is created or destroyed.

Also, counter_cache functionality can easily be added to existing databases as [demonstrated here](http://blog.obiefernandez.com/content/2011/08/adding-a-counter-cache-to-existing-records.html), by Obie Fernandez.

Answer (score 2):

In articles#index you can loop through the instance variable that contains all of the articles.  Your view should look something like this:

```
@articles.each do |article|
  article.name
  .
  .
  article.comments.count
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@article.comments
```

will give all the comments for the @article. You dont need to specify as below

```
@article.comments.find(:all)
```

for displaying the count of comments for every article, do

```
%table
  %thead
  %tbody
    - @articles.each do |article|
      %tr
      = article.comments.count
```

the view is in haml